# Maximum likelihood method

Tags: maximum-likelihood, optimization

I try to calibration the parameters $\theta$ of my probabilistic model from available (limited) information at some point $\mathbf{x}_i, i=(1,...,n)$ on a 3D space defined by $[0, M]^3 \subset \mathbb{R}^3$. If I have *sufficient* point ($n$ is sufficient large) , I can make use of Maximum Likelihood method:

$$\theta_\text{mle} = \text{argmax }\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{x; \theta})$$

In which $\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{x}; \theta)$ is the (multidimensional) likelihood function.

Does it exist an optimal choice of point $\mathbf{x}_i$ (the arrangement of these point in space) so that the number of point $n$ is minimal?

Comment: You have to be a *little* bit more specific because as for now you say that you have *some* model and ask if it is possible to estimate it using ML. As for now the answer is: yes, no, maybe.

Comment: your measurement is $x_i$, or some function _evaluated in_ $x_i$?

Comment: The answer often is "yes" but it depends (strongly) on what you mean by "optimal."  You need to supply a quantitative measure of (expected) "goodness" of the fit as well as constraints on it. For instance, you might want to assure the determinant of the covariance matrix of the parameter estimates is less than some target value. But there are many other criteria one might use.  What are yours?

Comment: @chuse: my measurement at $\mathbf{x}_i$ is a scalar.